# Eight-bit two’s complement question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider an 8-bit two’s complement register R. What are the least and greatest decimal integers that can be stored in R?
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what your thoughts and attempts are thus far?

Comment: @Amzoti Is the least 00000000 and the greatest 11111111 ? I'm not entirely sure what the "register R" means.

Comment: The register is just called $R$.

Comment: It means "you have 8 bits, what's the biggest and smallest number you can store in it, assuming you're using two's complement". The name of the register doesn't really matter.

Comment: The greatest cannot be 11111111, because the sign bit is set to 1, so it represents a negative number.

Comment: Did you get the nick correct? :-)

Comment: >Klazy haha. @Amzoti can you check my comment on the answer please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 8 bits, so you can store $256 = 2^8$ distinct integers. Since you are using two's complemnt, the range is $-128..127$.  You store $127$ as $01111111$ and $-128$ as
$10000000$.

A register is just high-speed non-addressable memory near the CPU. The registers are used as caches for high-speed computation.

Comment: So would the greatest be be 10000000 and smallest 00000000 ?

Comment: see pp.22ff in http://www.ncssm.edu/~morrison/froobles/c0.pdf

Comment: I'm confused. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Do you know how two's complement works?

Comment: very helpful, thanks !